# EntityFramework.Extended Update not working - can't convert DynamicProxy

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-extended

I am using Entity Framework 6 and tried to use EntityFramework.Extended to do some batch updates:

```
db.TicketOrderItems
  .Where(i => !i.IsDeleted && !i.Order.IsCompleted && i.Order.OrderDate < margin)
  .Update(i => new TicketOrderItem { IsDeleted = true });
```

TicketOrderItem is an extension of OrderItem. When this is now executed I get the following error (translated from german, as I get it in german):

```
The EntityFramework.Reflection.DynamicProxy-type can not implicitly be converted 
to System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<NAMESPACE.TicketOrderItem>.
```

I already disabled lazy loading and proxy generation (and verified it via debugging, that no proxies are generated):

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

**Is there a way to fix that?**
Or is this a bug in the "not yet final" EF 6 or an incompability between EF.Extended and EF 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works not with the current version of EF.Extended.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like EntityFramework.Extended doesn't work with EF 6 yet. Some of EF namespace changes are causing the problem. You can pull the extended source, remove the old EF reference and change the EF related namespaces from

```
using System.Data.*;
```

to

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.*;
```